# Is there a more elegant pythonic way of expressing the following condional expression?

Tags: python

I would like a more pythonic way for the following branch if any:

```
if a<b:
   a.append('value')
elif a==b:
   b.append('value')
else:
   do nothing
```

Is there any ternary operator for that?

Comment: _Pythoniceans_ **love** the word _pythonic_, even when it means nothing.

Comment: What's wrong with using 6 lines?

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it if your three `do sth`s are very different. If they can be parametrized, the branch could be written more concisely. Tell us more about your `do sth`s.

Comment: @GrantThomas while that is somewhat true, I usually use it as 'conforming to the most things in `import this`' :)

Comment: How about `[lambda: a, lambda: b, lambda: c][(a < b) + (a <= b)]`

Comment: @eumiro i change the question appropriately. Yes the do sth is parametrized.

Comment: @Blender, can be written more concisely using `cmp(a,b)` :)

Comment: what is do sth? a function or assignment?

Comment: @gnibbler: Now *this* I will be using. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a nested ternary operator.

```
func1() if a<b else func2() if a==b else func3()
```

For your specific example:

```
a.append('value') if a<b else b.append('value') if a==b else None
```

Comment: now you got me in the golfing mood `[func2,func3,func1][cmp(a,b)]()`

Answer (score 4):

Obviously you can just leave the else case off

```
if a<b:
   a.append('value')
elif a==b:
   b.append('value')
```

Comment: This is the only _real_ improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
result = a<b and first_action or a==b and second_action or third_action
```

Where *_action fits the "do sth" code in your question

Comment: While `and/or`-tricking it works, it just makes it much less readable imo.

Comment: @AttilaO. I think tricking is a leading adjective. Short-cutting AND logic is common in most languages... And I'm a fan :)

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
if a<b:
   a.append('value')
elif a==b:
   b.append('value')
else:
   do nothing
```

cannot be much rewritten, it is OK as it is. Maybe just remove the last two lines (else/do nothing).

The only parametrization I see here is:

```
if a <= b:
    (a,b)[a==b].append('value')
```

but that's simply ugly.

Comment: @curious. Yeah, and he has considered them as different only. Look at the answer again clearly.

Comment: @curious - is it? It does *anything* only if `a<=b`. Then it does two different things depending on whether `a<b` or `a==b`. It works, it is just ugly.

Answer (score 0):

For your *exact* case, one of these will work:

```
[b, a, []][cmp(x, y)].append('value')
[b, a, []][cmp(x, y)] += ['value']
```

Please don't do this. Your current code is easy to read.

Comment: Did I start some sort of a golf competition?